# Pros and Cons of building Zend_Form with Zend_Config

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form, zend-config

Has anyone out there built their Zend Form's with their configuration files?  I'm thinking that this wouldn't be a bad idea since I could then have other applications/languages parse/create/modify a form (e.g. a zend form builder application.)  I'm sure there are some downsides to this.  Anyone had any experience doing this?

-Strick

Answer (score 0):

If you use Zend_Config to construct Zend_Form you will have to parse the INI file; this is extremely marginal performance decrease. The increase in clarity and isolation of the configuration outweigh these disadvantages. Do keep in mind if you ever extend Zend_Form to add more functionality you may need to extend the setOptions() method to support your changes.